# How do I priority Queue implementation using circular queue in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue

Getting element value in the queue with the highest priority should be preferred.

Comment: it is not a queue by definition. Use heap instead.

Comment: There's a std::priority_queue.

Comment: Seems to have generated some friction. Maybe you could add some context -- how many levels of priority do you have; what's the wider goal, or is this an abstract question; I'd assume you're wanting a priority queue of some fixed size? That might help some of the commenters answer directly ...

Answer (score 0):

Do you instead need multiple queues, each with different priorities? What's the problem you're actually trying to solve?

The idea of a queue is -- that it's a queue, and what's next in the queue has priority, and you should only go through the queue by popping stuff off it. Implementing a priority queue with another queue -- whether circular or not -- isn't the most efficient thing to do. You can implement it as a heap or tree instead -- there are a number of articles, including one on [Wikipedia on priority queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).

Comment: Yeah, and a priority queue is different http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue

Comment: If we are talking about many levels of priority (1000 for instance) then multiple queues are not the best solution.

Comment: @Falmarri -- not sure if you read or interpreted my answer correctly. Making a priority queue with another queue doesn't make any sense -- think you missed the point.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a priority queue implemented as a binary min heap.  The keys of each entry could represent its "priority" and the lower the key, the more priority it has.  Thus, removing the root entry will return the entry with the highest priority.